# iOS 9.2.1 app crash on launch

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ios9.2.1

*My app works fine in all the versions except iOS 9.2.1*

*When I run the app on device directly from Xcode I am not experiencing the problem in iOS 9.2.1*

**Clarification:**

*I guess iOS kills my app because its consuming more memory and the app is signed by ad-hoc or distribution certificate.
when running from xcode I am not facing the problem because its signed by developer certificate and so iOS not kills the app and lets it run*

Here is the device log that I got from xcode *devices* while launching the app

> Feb 17 15:27:58 test-iPhone-6 SpringBoard[58] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 SpringBoard[58] :  SecTrustEvaluate
> [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59
> test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements
> MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59
> test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :  secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements
> MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored taskRef found Feb 17 15:27:59
> test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf
> IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6
> kernel[0] : xpcproxy[365] Container:
> /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E0E7AB14-7B51-4B34-8CAE-5A31D96CF800
> (sandbox)
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName] Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 securityd[91] :
> secTaskDiagnoseEntitlements MISSING keychain entitlements: no stored
> taskRef found
>
> Feb 17 15:27:59 test-iPhone-6 amfid[168] :
> SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
>
> Feb 17
> 15:28:00 test-iPhone-6 SpringBoard[58] : BSXPCMessage
> received error for message: Connection invalid
>
> Feb 17 15:28:00
> test-iPhone-6 SpringBoard[58] : HW kbd: Failed to set (null)
> as keyboard focus
>
> Feb 17 15:28:00 test-iPhone-6 mediaserverd[28]
> : '' com.test.myappname(pid = 365) setting DiscoveryMode =
> DiscoveryMode_None, currentDiscoveryMode = DiscoveryMode_None
>
> Feb 17
> 15:28:00 test-iPhone-6 diagnosticd[83] : error evaluating
> process info - pid: 365, puniqueid: 365
>
> Feb 17 15:28:00 test-iPhone-6
> SpringBoard[58] : BSXPCMessage received error for message:
> Connection invalid
>
> Feb 17 15:28:00 test-iPhone-6
> com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
> (UIKitApplication:com.test.myappname[0x632d][365]) : Service
> exited due to signal: Segmentation fault:
>
> 11 Feb 17 15:28:00
> test-iPhone-6 ReportCrash[366] : Formulating report for
> corpse[365] myappnameSwift
>
> Feb 17 15:28:00 test-iPhone-6
> ReportCrash[366] : saved type '109_myappnameSwift' report (5
> of max 25) as
> /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/myappnameSwift_2016-02-17-152800_test-iPhone-6.ips
>
> Feb 17 15:28:00 test-iPhone-6 SpringBoard[58] : Application
> 'UIKitApplication:com.test.myappname[0x632d]' crashed.
>
> Feb 17 15:28:00
> test-iPhone-6 UserEventAgent[26] : 289017674762:
> id=com.test.myappname pid=365, state=0

Comment: Is this app built with App Store provisioning or Enterprise? And is it so much iOS 9.2.1, or just a particular device (i.e. does this happen on iOS 9.2.1 across numerous devices each with 9.2.1 installed; or is this just a single device)?  As well, if you try launching the app again (and perhaps a 3rd or 4th time... just keep trying to launch it), does it eventually launch, or does it never launch no matter how many consecutive attempts you make?

Comment: It says it's saving a crash report at "/var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/myappnameSwift_2016-02-17-152800_test-iPhone-6.ips".  What does that contain?

Comment: @hsoi - Enterprise provisioning.I tried launching the app many times like 20 but it always crashes

Comment: @PhillipMills - Here is the link to [crash log](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc/issues/571)

Comment: Symbolicate frame 10 and it might tell you something useful.  A list of numeric addresses is a waste of time.

Comment: I asked because I frequently saw this same SecTrustEvaluate cascade and failures to launch immediately (sometimes needed 2-4 launches). In my case, it's the OS trying to reconcile the provisioning, and I have LOTS of provisioning profiles. I went into Xcode->Window->Devices, selected my attached phone, gear menu on bottom-left, "Show Provisioning Profiles" and went through and deleted as much as I could. Now with only a handful of relevant profiles, my enterprise apps launch quickly. YMMV.

Comment: @hsoi - it never ever launches in the particular OS.When I run from xcode I am not facing this problem. so something is obviously wrong while running the app that is signed by adhoc or distribution profile for sure

Comment: Similar experience - I run my app via Debug from Xcode, no problems. Launch app (Enterprise Distribution provisioned) directly -- same device -- and fails to launch. So likely a provisioning issue. First thing I'd say would be to check that device's provisioning profiles as I mentioned above and delete profiles until you have truly just the ones you need (not the ones Xcode has bloated the device up with over the years). See if that helps. Best I can think. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the ***Architectures*** in ***Build Settings*** solved my problem

[image]

Changed the architecture from ***$(ARCHS_STANDARD)*** to ***$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)***